# Compilation of Tefillot for specific purposes

Tags: tefilla, tehilim-psalms

It is clear from the Gemara in brachot there is a real science behind tefillah and in addition to needing the appropriate emotional-mind state you also need to formulate your petition according to the proper protocol established by the Holy One.

The *shemonah esrei* addresses very general matters which pertain to Jewry as a whole. Due to the generic nature of shemonah esrei as well as the generally diminished state of god awareness of contemporary Jewry as a whole it's not clear that the average Abe would get a specific need answered through the more klal-oriented shemonah esrei.

Supposing someone wants to really pinpoint a specific issue in davening, I'm wondering if any sage has written or anthologized tefillot in which one can find a tefillah calibrated to this or that specific need.

Tehillim is certainly the first go to compilation of tefillot and really should be all I need. In theory you should be able to get answered through tehillim. It was written with ruach hakodesh.

On the other hand, are you aware of other compilations, probably written more in relatively modern Jewish history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you ask about a *specific* sage compiling a sefer of tefillos, I'll answer with the [Likutei Tefillos](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/61958) of Reb Noson miBreslov. It covers a broad range of topics, and has an extensive [index](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=61958&st=&pgnum=1492) by topic; the [BRI translation](https://books.breslov.org/product/fiftieth-gate-likutey-teffilot-7-vol-set/) contains a short description of what each tefillah is for in the table of contents and the beginning of each tefillah.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Sefer Segulos and Tefillos from R' Aron Zakkai]

There's literally hundreds of these types of seforim. This is one I found on my shelf that someone once gave as a gift.

Each tefilla has the source included (the Shel"a, Bais Tefilla etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The Gemara in Brachot is focusing on fulfilling one's obligation to pray. If you are praying additional prayers on your own, there are less rules. That being said, many prayers were written by later rabbis for a large variety of issues. A good seforim store should be able to help you find the right one for you.

Comment: if you read the fifth perek it is discussing the technical parameters of tefillah and what gets a tefillah answered and what to do if you're not answered, i.e. the mechanics of tefillah. either way, ha gufa is my question, i.e. what are the names of some of these seforim.